# Image prefetching using <link> tag

Tags: html

I have seen sites using  tag to load images eg;

```
<link href='images.jpg' rel='somthing' type='something'>
```

what relevance does this have while designing a website? 
What aspect of website does it help optimize( i am thinking it's used for optimization. Right me if i am wrong). Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some people use this for image/css/page prefetching. You can [read about it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ)

Basically, once a page is finished loading the browser will see these `link` tags and if the `rel` attribute is "next" or "prefetch" then the browser will start downloading whatever the `href` attribute points to and store it in the cache so that it will load very fast if the user clicks on it.

This method can be used to prefetch anything including images, style sheets, different web pages, etc. As long as the url used in the `<link>` matches the url used to normally load the resource, it will load that resource from the cache.

For example, if your page had this link `<a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>` and you wanted to prefetch it, you would add this to your page `<link rel="next" href="page2.html">`.

Finally, this method of prefetching is preferred over the javascript methods because this type of prefetching is standards compliant, is handled by the browser, and can be disabled by the user if they have metered bandwidth or other connection limitations.

Comment: does this work only on images used on link(<a>) or does the caching allow the image to be loaded with the same path.(for example showing a hidden image using js manually adding the link)

Comment: @hengecyche This does not work on anchor `<a>` tags alone. You have to add a `<link rel="prefetch">` with the same URL. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: could you maybe explain the use case for it I mean in which parts of code is it useful to prefetch like in the navigation? or is it determined by users who 'propably would click it' eg UX design. Ive always been preloading through Javascript but today it seems not so productive anymore as it's done today much easier. Yet, in Javascript atleast I am able to decide when these are trigged to be preloaded but in HTML as a <link> they automatically download contents already at the begin which I not always want at first. I hope you know, what I mean.

Answer (score 14):

While a page loads, blocking scripts can interrupt, forcing other scripts to wait. `rel=preload` in a link element becomes **a declarative fetch primitive that initiates an early fetch and separates fetching from resource execution.**

`<link rel="preload" href="/style/other.css" as="style">`

`<link rel="preload" href="/assets/font.woff2" as="font">`

`<link rel="preload" href="/img/header.png" as="image">`

ref. https://w3c.github.io/preload/

take note that `preload` is PREliminary

Comment: have been experimenting with `preload` links in individual blog posts. loading the main `img` at the top of the post, soundcloud player, bandcamp player, youtube embed, etc. approaching a YouTube embed as a 'resource', I add `rel="preload"` alone. for general links to outside WebSites (which are not embeds) I add `rel="nofollow"` instead of `preload`.

Comment: For images I would suggest switch `preload` to `prefetching`, so you lower the "priority" of downloading  see here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/html-preload-prefetch#step-3-prefetching-resources